# how to install awscli.msi and upload files to s3 using .bat script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, windows-task-scheduler

I need to schedule a .bat file which will install AWS CLI on windows and then upload files daily form a local directory to AWS S3.

My script looks like -

```
:: AWS CLI MSI installer for Windows (64-bit): https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi
aws --version

:: Create S3 bucket (not public), set bucket name and region (different than your EC2 region for better disaster recovery plan)
:: You can access your S3 bucket via CLI simply using s3://bucket-name
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID {access_key_here}
aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY {secret_key_here}
aws s3 cp local_directory/* s3://{bucket_name_here}/

echo "complete"
```

I don't understand how the AWSCLI64.msi will be downloaded and installed through this script? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do all the processes through **Batch** or **Powershell** (I prefer this more)

```
@echo off
:: AWS CLI MSI installation
SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\AWSCLI64.msi"
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi "%FILENAME%"
msiexec /i "%FILENAME%" /qn /norestart

:: AWS CLI configuration
set userprofile=C:\Users\%username%
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <IAM_KEY>
aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY <IAM_SECRET>
aws configure set default.region <REGION>

:: S3 Bucket backup
aws s3 cp local_directory/* s3://{bucket_name_here}/
echo "complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you.Run the commands on powershell.

Set-AWSCredentials –AccessKey key-name –SecretKey key-name
Set-DefaultAWSRegion `-Region us-east-2 Get-SSMDocumentList Get-SSMDocumentList Get-SSMDocumentDescription`
-Name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript"
Get-SSMDocumentDescription `-Name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" | Select -ExpandProperty Parameters $runPSCommand = Send-SSMCommand`
-InstanceIds @("instance-ID-1", "instance-ID-2") `-DocumentName "AWS-RunPowerShellScript"`
-Comment "Demo AWS-RunPowerShellScript with two instances" `-Parameter @{'commands'=@('dir C:\Users', 'dir C:\')} Get-SSMCommand`
-CommandId $runPSCommand.CommandId
Get-SSMCommandInvocation `-CommandId $runPSCommand.CommandId Get-SSMCommandInvocation`
-CommandId $runPSCommand.CommandId `-Details $true`
-InstanceId instance-ID | Select -ExpandProperty CommandPlugins

Get-SSMDocumentDescription `-Name "AWS-InstallApplication" Get-SSMDocumentDescription`
-Name "AWS-InstallApplication" | Select -ExpandProperty Parameters
$installAppCommand = Send-SSMCommand `-InstanceId instance-ID`
-DocumentName "AWS-InstallApplication" `-Parameter @{'source'='https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/python-2.7.9.msi'; 'parameters'='/norestart /quiet /log c:\pythoninstall.txt'} Get-SSMCommandInvocation`
-CommandId $installAppCommand.CommandId `-Details $true Get-SSMCommandInvocation`
-CommandId $installAppCommand.CommandId `-Details $true`
-InstanceId instance-ID | Select -ExpandProperty CommandPlugins
$installPSCommand = Send-SSMCommand `-InstanceId instance-ID`
-DocumentName "AWS-InstallPowerShellModule" `-Parameter @{'source'='https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/EZOut-33ae0fb7/file/110351/1/EZOut.zip';'commands'=@('Add-WindowsFeature -name XPS-Viewer -restart')}`
-OutputS3BucketName demo-ssm-output-bucket
Get-SSMCommandInvocation `-CommandId $installPSCommand.CommandId`
-Details $true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).